# R vector error using SQL query to get ID's

Tags: sql, r, sql-server

I am using the RADWords impelementation from here -  https://jburkhardt.github.io/RAdwords/

Unfortunately it does not provide a way to get a summary for every Account in an Adwords MCC. So I have created a script to push a list of accountIds to Google Big Query and then pull this down to my SQL Server to use.

It is possible to loop through accounts as suggested here.
https://github.com/jburkhardt/RAdwords/issues/6

I would like to use my account list via sql to get this, but I am getting the error below and this I need to use the "paste" function in order to separate my values when creating the vector...

"EXECUTE statement failed because its WITH RESULT SETS clause specified 13 column(s) for result set number 1, but the statement sent 1 column(s) at run time."

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Kind Regards
John Broomfield

[R vector create error radwords](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HeGI.png)

Comment: I got this working using the code below and some help from Johannes Burkhardt. Code used is shown below and I was able to dynamically loop through a list of active Adwords clients via SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

With some help from Johannes Burkhardt, I was able to get the loop script working in R. The code is shown below. I was also able to get this working dynamically from a list of all Adwords clients in SQL Server if anyone is interested...

```
library(RAdwords)
google_auth <- doAuth()
body <- statement(select=c('AccountDescriptiveName','ExternalCustomerId','CustomerDescriptiveName','AccountCurrencyCode','CampaignName','CampaignId','CampaignStatus','CampaignGroupId','AdNetworkType1','Cost,'AverageCpc','Ctr','AveragePosition','Impressions','Clicks','CostPerConversion','ConversionRate','Date','Device')
report="CAMPAIGN_PERFORMANCE_REPORT",where="CampaignStatus = 'ENABLED'",start="2018-10-01",end="2018-10-30")
#vector of account IDs - NB: I populated this from a variable in SQL 
accounts <- c("xxx-xxx-xxxx","xxx-xxx-xxxx","xxx-xxx-xxxx","xxx-xxx-xxxx","xxx-xxx-xxxx")
#loop over accounts and rbind data to dataframe
loopData <- function(){
  for(i in 1:length(accounts)){
    if (i == 1){
      xy <- getData(clientCustomerId=accounts[i],statement=body,google_auth = google_auth,transformation=TRUE,changeNames=TRUE)
    }
    else {
      xz <- getData(clientCustomerId=accounts[i],statement=body,google_auth = google_auth,transformation=TRUE,changeNames=TRUE)
      xy <- rbind(xy,xz)
    }
  }
  return(xy)
}
data <- loopData()
OutputDataSet <- as.data.frame(data)
OutputDataSet
```